Ubuntu 24 Black Screen Almost Every Day
I'm using:
Ubuntu 24
Linux user 6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul  5 21:49:14 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Errors that lead to this issue i think are:
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:21 2024] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.I2C0.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/dswload2-162)
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:21 2024] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:21 2024] ACPI Error: For GPE 0x14, found both _L14 and _E14 methods (20230628/evgpeinit-398)

[Tue Aug  6 21:58:25 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:26 2024] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.LPCB.HEC.CFSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:26 2024] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.H_EC.TFN1._FST due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:26 2024] acpi INTC10A2:00: Get fan state failed
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:27 2024] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:27 2024] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:28 2024] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ETIMEDOUT: PPM init failed
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[Tue Aug  6 21:58:45 2024] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

Nvidia Smi
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.183.01             Driver Version: 535.183.01   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 ...    Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P3              N/A /  35W |      8MiB /  6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3471      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


sudo prime-select intel  and disable Nvidia GPU for now
